# Finding Optimal Popup Window Size with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, dojo

I have a small popup window with dynamic contents. Nothing too complex. It has just a table with some text in it.

How do I find the height and the width of a window so that its content will show entirely?

The problem with using arbitrary, static values for the window's dimension is that it can be way off depending on the browser's font settings.

If this is not possible, what are the common practices?

Thanks.

Comment: Something like `$(win).width(win.innerWidth).height(win.innerHeight)`?

Comment: Actually I'm not using jQuery. I'm using dojo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copy the HTML contents you want to put in the popup into a div that's positioned off the page, measure it, then remove the div. I don't know dojo, sorry, but this is a way to do it in jQuery:

```
var measuringDiv = $('<div class="sameAsPopupContainer" style="position:absolute; left:9999px; top:0px"></div>');
$('body').append(measuringDiv);
measuringDiv.html(theHtmlForTheTable);
heightOfContent = measuringDiv.width();
widthOfContent = measuringDiv.height();
measuringDiv.remove();
```

I assume dojo has similar methods. It's important that the off-page div you're creating maintains the same style rules as the popup container, which can be a little tricky.